# React/Rails error - A valid React element (or null) must be returned

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I'm building a very simple blog app with React on the front-end and Rails on the backend. I can't quite figure out how to handle this error:

```
 Uncaught Error: Posts.render(): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.
```

I have two react components, Post and Posts. Both are extremely simple. Here is Posts:

```
var Posts = React.createClass({ 
    getInitialState: function(){
        return { 
            posts: this.props.posts
        }
    },
    render: function(){ 
            var that = this; 
            var postBoard = this.state.posts.map(function(post){
                return (
                <Post post={post} key={post.id} />
                );
            });
        return (
            { postBoard }
        );
    }
});
```

Here is Post:

```
var Post = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return {
            post: this.props.post
        }
    },
    render: function(){
        return (
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h3>{this.state.post.title}</h3>
                <p>{this.state.post.content}</p>
            </div>
        ); 
    }
});
```

Here is the Rails index view for Posts. I am using the react-rails gem:

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-3">
    <h1>Posts</h1>
    <%= react_component( "Posts", { posts: @posts }) %> 
    <br>
    <%= link_to 'New Post', new_post_path %>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the index action in my Posts controller:

```
 def index
    @posts = Post.all
 end
```

I can't figure out what is causing this. It's been a few weeks since I've used React. I am clearly rusty. Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap `postBoard` inside div. The reason of error is return methods return only one element.  In your case `postBoard` is array. If the length of `postBoard` array is equal to 1, it should work without wraping it inside `div` element

```
return (
    <div>        
    { postBoard }
    </div> 
   );
```